# Find out if objects have same keys

Tags: javascript, algorithm, underscore.js

I have a pair of objects. I'm trying to find out if they both have the same keys, like so:

```
let a = { user1: true, user2: true }
let b = { user1: true, user3: true }
hasSameKeys(a, b) => false

let a = { user1: true, user2: true }
let b = { user2: true, user1: true }
hasSameKeys(a, b) => true
```

I'm also using _underscore.js

Thanks in advance

John S.

Comment: by "if they have the same keys" do you mean an exact match? One can't have more than the other? Also, please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test if they have the same number of keys and if every one of one object's keys are contained in the other:

```js
function hasSameKeys(a, b){
    return Object.keys(a).length === Object.keys(b).length
    && Object.keys(a).every(k => b.hasOwnProperty(k))
}

let a = { user1: true, user2: true }
let b = { user1: true, user3: true }
console.log(hasSameKeys(a, b) )


a = { user1: true, user2: true }
b = { user2: true, user1: true }
console.log(hasSameKeys(a, b) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var a1 = { user1: true, user2: true }
var b1 = { user2: true, user1: true }
var c1 = { ...a1, ...b1}
var a1b1SameKeys = Object.keys(a1).length === Object.keys(b1).length && Object.keys(a1).length === Object.keys(c1).length
console.log (a1b1SameKeys) // true

var a2 = { user1: true, user2: true }
var b2 = { user1: true, user3: true }
var c2 = { ...a2, ...b2}
var a2b2SameKeys = Object.keys(a2).length === Object.keys(b2).length && Object.keys(a2).length === Object.keys(c2).length
console.log (a2b2SameKeys) // false


var a3 = { user1: true, user2: true, foo: true }
var b3 = { user1: true, user2: true, bar: false }
var c3 = { ...a3, ...b3}
var a2b2SameKeys = Object.keys(a3).length === Object.keys(b3).length && Object.keys(a3).length === Object.keys(c3).length
console.log (a2b2SameKeys) // false
```

Comment: Doesn't this just tell you if they have the same number of keys? e.g. if one object had a key `foo` and the other had a key `bar` they would both be the same length, but contain different keys.

Comment: @scunliffe if there were different keys in the two objects, then `c1` would be longer. The only way a1, b1 and c1 can all be the same length is if you added no more keys to c1 you merge the tow objects to create it.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that c1/c2 were merging the objects. Although this would work, it seems like a bad idea to create a new object (with the potential size of both originals combined) only to check if the keys are the same.

Comment: yes, if one object had a key `foo` and the other had a key `bar` than `c1.length` will be grather than `a1.length` or `b1.length`. I added this example into the answer

Comment: I agree that Mark's answer is better, just wanted to post some different approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you're using underscore, you can also use [`isEqual`](https://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) on sorted arrays of keys:

```js
function hasSameKeys(a, b) {
  return _.isEqual(_.keys(a).sort(), _.keys(b).sort()); 
}

let a = { user1: true, user2: true };
let b = { user1: true, user3: true };
console.log(hasSameKeys(a, b));

a = { user1: true, user2: true };
b = { user2: true, user1: true };
console.log(hasSameKeys(a, b));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```